# How do i create a remote HTML Login page to log into the targets website

Tags: html, asp.net, authentication, remote-access, login-script

The problem: I need to create a simple standalone HTML snippet login tool that i can use on another domain that will then access my targets database (Using their API parameters) by sending an SSL request to it. If a login is successful than it gets transferred to the targets landing page, if the login is unsuccessful than it goes to a "bad login page", however all of this is handled by my target.

So i want to be able to log into www.target.com from www.example.com

1. www.example.com Houses the remote login code (HTML Website)
2. www.target.com Houses the database of users and passwords

On my targets web.config i have LoginRemoteURLAllowed and then am able to set the request url to match the domain my HTML snippet is located on.

The reason being for me wanting to do this is that i have two separate sites with separate domains. One for a general public product catalog, the second domain is a private members only catalog that you have to login to access.

We already have a system like this set up, however i did not design it and I'm trying to reverse engineer it to create a standalone html file containing the login core that i can use on other websites.

Here is what I'm trying to reverse engineer. exert from the current working model (Taken directly off the example website using code inspector).

HTML Code for input management

```
label>Example Login</label>                
<div id="formMC_pnl" class="group" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, &#39;formMC_btnMCSubmit&#39;)">

<input name="formMC$txtMCUserName" type="text" value="Username" id="formMC_txtMCUserName" class="txtField" placeholder="Username" onfocus="if (this.value==&#39;Usernname&#39;) { this.value=&#39;&#39; };" onblur="if (this.value==&#39;&#39;) { this.value=&#39;Username&#39; };" />

<input name="formMC$txtMCPassword" type="password" id="formMC_txtMCPassword" class="txtField pass" placeholder="Password" onfocus="if (this.value==&#39;Password&#39;) { this.value=&#39;&#39; };" onblur="if (this.value==&#39;&#39;) { this.value=&#39;Password&#39; };" />

<input type="submit" name="formMC$btnMCSubmit" value="Login" id="formMC_btnMCSubmit" class="btnSubmit" />
```

Now im assuming that it uses a webform to connect to my site, but im not sure how it does it. Heres the exert of the webform used

```
function WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, target) {
if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    var src = event.srcElement || event.target;
    if (src &&
        ((src.tagName.toLowerCase() == "input") &&
         (src.type.toLowerCase() == "submit" || src.type.toLowerCase() == "button")) ||
        ((src.tagName.toLowerCase() == "a") &&
         (src.href != null) && (src.href != "")) ||
        (src.tagName.toLowerCase() == "textarea")) {
        return true;
    }
    var defaultButton;
    if (__nonMSDOMBrowser) {
        defaultButton = document.getElementById(target);
    }
    else {
        defaultButton = document.all[target];
    }
    if (defaultButton && typeof(defaultButton.click) != "undefined") {
        defaultButton.click();
        event.cancelBubble = true;
        if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

}

So now im just wondering if it is possible to make a standalone html remote login to access my targets database and verify/login the user . Any and all help would be appreciated, I've tried to provide as much information about the issue as i can. Let me know if i can clarify anything further. More or less i want to replicate this working model so i can add it to a www.example.com and log into www.target.com from example.

Answer (score 0):

You can't authenticate cross domain.

At best you could have the site hit the database validate the username and password and then generate a GUID store it in the user table and return it to the user to store in a cookie.

Once the cookie is returned and created then redirect to the target site. Then validate the GUID in the cookie on land. This would also require either a page or code in the global.asax or a authentication.cs page in the AppCode that validates and either creates the session or redirects.

If the GUID isn't valid then redirect i.e. string.empty or doesn't match a GUID in the database.

Comment: I dont think im trying to authenticate cross domains, rather pass on information entered from one (a username and password) and send it to the other target domain which handles the authentication. The target is set to accept remote login parameters through given API parameters. Once logged in, i dont return to the original site, instead im logged in on my target site. The process already works on the site i was given, i am just having a hard time reverse engineering it to recreate the remote login process. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: @user2665682 but how do you store the authentication cross domain.  Plus sessions don't go from domain to domain so the only way I know how to do this is the GUID and a cookie and then authenticating on land.

Comment: Gotcha. Can you recommend any tutorials? It seems pretty complicated unfortunatly. Not sure how the original desiner accomplished this in my example unless the two website are part of the same domain. They are housed on the same server i believe. As an alterntive do you think it would be possible to make a HTML Microsite that handles the login credentials as part of the target domain, than display that microsite on the example website. I.e. the log in form (Microsite) is house at www.target.com/MicroLogin.aspx than embed that on www.example.com so once you login it redirects you to the target.

Comment: Since we really dont need the login information on the example site this could be possible. However, i would want it to close the old site and redirect it to the new site once you login and not just redirect the microsite.

Comment: @user2665682 that's why I was saying when you authenticate from the site (since the database doesn't care what site you are coming from) then when authentication is successful update the user authentication table with a GUID reference http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/076c71fa-add4-4c6f-9b3c-f9f1cbea3de3/how-to-create-guid-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral then return that GUID to the person authenticating store it in a cookie and then redirect them to the site.  Have the site validate the cookie reference the user and create the session on land.